# does logitech C922 Pro compatible with ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: compatibility, logitech

I am going to buy a webcam to be installed in Ubuntu 16.04. I am going to use it for skype

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look into [ubuntu webcam help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam) which handles this topic pretty thoroughly.

You may also search the [list of devices supported by uvc driver](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/) directly.

Afaik there is no luck with c922.